# searching tool to read defect ntfs partition on the fly

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

i have a hdd crash by physical influence (laptop fell down 0,5 m while disk running)

after connecting the disk to a notebook via USB adapter, i could see 1 of 4 partitions with a drive letter, the one  i didnt need :(

using linux i could see the one linux partion also, but could not mount the one ntfs of interest, linux mention it broken i should run chkdisk under windows what i didnt.

using Active partition rcovery, i was able to see the partiion and the filetree, but saving an imgae of this 200 gb partion takes already 9 hours for 2 gb what makes an estimated time of 900 hours!

my question, an belive me i googled aready for hours:
is there a tool which can mout the disk and copy some files in a read only mode without writing to the disk? the part where the data of interest lies seems to be ok, but with the tools i have i cant get the files, just "repair" what i dont want in case i need a rescue company

any help/ links apreciated

Comment: `i have a hdd crash by physical influence (laptop fell down 0,5 m while disk running)` This is one of the primary benefits of SSDs, you can throw laptops around without much worry. If only they could just fix the limited-writes issue…

Comment: to mount an ntfs partion becomes quick obsolete ? you sheriffs of stack xxx are paranoid! 
@synetech: good point ;(

Comment: It wasn’t closed because mounting a partition gets obsolete, they closed it because they don’t like it if you ask for programs to do stuff (even though the same programs have been used for years and almost *all* questions end up requiring a program anyway…) You are better off editing your question to remove anything like “tell me a program that…” or “what program can…?” Replace those with something like “how can I…?” and “is there a way to…?” Then let *them* recommend a program. (Yes, that’s silly and pointless and ends up right back at square one, but that’s how they like it for some reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem some time ago. Three partitions just disappeared one day.

I tried several tools and found program "Find and Mount". It does exactly what name says: finds NTFS partitions and mounts them in read-only mode. I rescued 200GB of my work in an hour.